# Pass function output to find the string passed as argument into function output from input file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a simple function which will give me past one hour log

```
past_hour_log(){
    awk -v Date1=$(date -d"now 1 hour ago" "+%H:%M:%S") -v Date2=$(date -d"now 1 hour ago" "+%d") ' { if ($3 > Date1 && $2 >= Date2) {print $0}} ' /var/log/syslog
}
```

My function Output :

```
Oct  9 12:15:15 localhost-IdeaPad-980 systemd[1]: time has been changed
Oct  9 12:16:00 localhost-IdeaPad-980 systemd[1534]: time has been changed
Oct  9 12:17:00 localhost-IdeaPad-980 systemd-timesyncd[25237]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Oct  9 12:17:01 localhost-IdeaPad-980 CRON[27685]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct  9 12:17:01 localhost-IdeaPad-980 CRON[29613]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

So here on next line, I am trying to pass this function output into grep xargs to get a total count of the string given as input from **input.txt**

```
TIME_COUNT="$(cat input.txt | xargs -I{} grep {} past_hour_log | awk '{print $7}' | awk -F '?' '{print $1}' | uniq -c)"
```

But the output shows me below. Are there any ideas to achieve this?

> grep: past_hour_log: No such file or directory

Comment: @Inian: Kindly understand the description given  and mark as duplicate.

Comment: Your requirement is an exact duplicate of the one I've given. Just export your function as `export -f past_hour_log` before calculating `TIME_COUNT`

Comment: I try export but the error i get 'export: Illegal option -f'

Comment: I need some exact solution for my question how this can be used. I am new to shell.

Comment: First of all, I see some serious quoting problems in your function `past_hour_log`. Could you fix those first and come back to us?

Comment: @SreedharanR was this answer helpful?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to attempt the following:

```
past_hour_log() {
    date1=$(date -d"now 1 hour ago" "+%H:%M:%S")
    date2=$(date -d"now 1 hour ago" "+%d")
    awk -v Date1="$date1" -v Date2="$date2" '($3 > Date1 && $2 >= Date2){print}' /var/log/syslog;
}
```

and then do

```
TIME_COUNT="$(past_hour_log | grep -F -f input.txt | awk '{print $7}' | awk -F '?' '{print $1}' | uniq -c)"
```

Comment: Kindly refer this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772238/print-next-value-compared-string-from-external-source-and-form-a-array